# Equation with expectations and squares

Tags: probability, expectation, random

Can somebody tell me, why the following is true:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{\alpha,\varepsilon} (f_{r}(\alpha,\varepsilon)-E[f_{r}])^{2}
=\sum_{\alpha,\varepsilon} f_{r}^2(\alpha,\varepsilon)-\sum_{\alpha,\varepsilon}E[f_{r}]^{2},
\end{equation}

where $f_{r}(\alpha,\epsilon)$ is a random variable on a sample space of $n_{(r)}2^r$ points, each having an equal probability.

Furthermore, we have
 $f_{r}(\alpha, \epsilon):=|\{v \in V:v \neq \alpha_{1},...,\alpha_{r}\text{ and } a(v,\alpha_{j})=\varepsilon_{j}, \forall\ 1\leq j\leq r\}|$ and $E[f_{r}(\alpha,\varepsilon)]=\frac{n-r}{2^r}$.

Comment: This looks like $E((X-\mu)^2)=E(X^2)-\mu^2$ for $\mu=E(X)$.

Comment: Yes, it should by the variace. Thanks @LordSharktheUnknown . This should work: $E[(f_{r}-E[f_{r}])^{2}]=\frac{1}{n_{(r)}2^{r}} \sum_{\alpha,\varepsilon}(f_{r}-E[f_{r}])^{2}=\frac{1}{n_{(r)}2^{r}} \sum_{\alpha,\varepsilon}f_{r}^{2}-E[f_{r}]^{2}$
multiplication with $n_{(r)}2^{r}$ on both sides implies the desired equation.